# How to install AASTEX with dependencies on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: aastex

Is there an apt-get command that can install AASTex on Ubuntu? What other packages and software would be recommended for using this?

Comment: I guess you just download the zip file and unpack it. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apt-cache search` to see what's available in your repos.  In your case:

```
jawguy@salix:~/$ apt-cache search aastex
texlive-publishers - TeX Live: Publisher styles, theses, etc.
```

So, there's something in the package texlive-publishers which is related to aastex.  You can see the file list of a particular package on the web:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/texlive-publishers/filelist

(swap 'precise' for your version)

And, you'll notice that
    /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/aastex/aastex.cls
    /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/aastex/aastex.sty

Are in that list.  So it seems like you just want to `sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers` and that should be that.