# Installing aastex package in Kile on Ubuntu 14

Tags: aastex

I tried everything (I think)!

- installing `texlive-publishers` following [How to install AASTEX with dependencies on Ubuntu 14.04](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314990/how-to-install-aastex-with-dependencies-on-ubuntu-14-04)
- installing the Vanilla TexLive, as indicated in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171560/9057

Now, aastex.sty IS present on my machine but Kile doesn't see it.
Below some info:
`kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` gives `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`
`locate aastex.sty` gives `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/aastex/aastex.sty`
if I try `texhash` I get

```
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done.
```

Can somebody, please, tell me what's wrong with my computer?
How can I make Kile see it and use it?

**UPDATE**
the compiler finds the downloaded .sty file if I place it in the same folder folder as the .tex file, but it's practically unusable since the compiler gives many errors.
should I first compile it separately? If so, with what? 
Thank you

Comment: Exactly what have you installed and exactly which latex is being used by your kile? (it is listed at the top of the log file). Note that ubuntu texlive and vanilla texlive does not share files. If aastex.sty is on ctan it is also available in vanilla texlive. So I'm guessing your kile is not using vanilla texlive.

Comment: I installed exactly what I linked above and the content of the (top of the) log file is the following:   `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.4.26)  2 MAY 2017 11:33
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**licentiate.tex
(./licentiate.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.` My suspect at this point is that Kile is not using Vanilla TexLive. If so, how do I change this? thank you

Comment: I'd like you to do a test, save this doc in `test.tex`: `\documentclass{article}\begin{dcument}hello\end{document}`. Then compile this in Kile, same the log file under another name, say `kile_log.log`, and then compile by hand in a terminal. Please post both logs. Then we can easily see whether they are using the same installation.

Comment: I compiled from terminal with `pdflatex` and its output is exactly the same as that of Kile: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.4.26)  2 MAY 2017 13:10
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.`

Comment: This is not the log. I'd like to see the full contents of the `.log` file. It also lists the path to files.

Comment: here it is http://txt.do/drvkt

Comment: That looks fine. Your `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/aastex/aastex.sty` is not part of vanilla texlive, it came with `texlive-publishers` that you installed via Ubuntu. Nowadays AAS does not use a `.sty` file, they have added a class file instead, `aastex6.cls` so you should probably use that.

Comment: and to add this class file I should look into <http://tug.org/tds/tds.pdf>, copy the class file to the right directory and then run `texhash` command, I suppose

Comment: no the class should already be part of the tex live you are using. Run `kpsewhich aastex6.cls` in a folder with no `.cls` files. You should just adjust your document to use the `aastex6` class, and not as a package.

Comment: I'm using a template for my document which already implements a custom class and replacing it with this class gives me all sorts of errors with the front page setup. I will simply remove the troublesome terms in the BibTex entries (such as `\apj`) and end of the story. I have a thesis to write, not LaTex on Ubuntu to debug. many thanks for your help and time @daleif

Comment: If you are planing to submit to AAS you should probably use their template not something custom. And you probably should not use a journal template to write a thesis. If you got that bibtex data online then of course it is unfortunate that it was not self contained, just edit the bibtex entry replacing the unknown macros. You did not mention any of this in your question, we could have fixed that issue in minutes.

Comment: no, I'm not going to submit to AAS, nor am I using a journal template. I'm using my Uni's own template. I was expecting this to work out-of-the-box, just like the journal templates. never mind. thanks once again for your help

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION (for all other unfortunate souls):
save this page http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty with `.sty` extension into the same directory as the `tex` file and add `\usepackage{aas_macros}` in the main document preamble